# Django View Testing Assertion Error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am testing my Django view:

```
self.assertEqual(response.context['area'], '<Area: a>')
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: <Area: a> != '<Area: a>'
```

What type is the part in angle brackets? What do I need to compare to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the area context variable is referring to an instance of Area, which is presumably a Django model. You are comparing it with a string. Either call `str()` explicitly on your context variable, or (preferably) compare with the actual Area object.